# Doing a proper Join with SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Suppose I have two tables, one with list of spells and another with a grimory, the list of spells that a user has selected for learn or already learned.

```
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM Grimory;
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| personage_id | int(11)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| spell_id     | int(11)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| isLearned    | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| isSelected   | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM Spell;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name            | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description     | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| chatDescription | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| level           | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| isActive        | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| category_id     | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| createdAt       | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**The problem.**

I want to display a list with ALL spells by category_id, BUT for every row I want to show if that spell is learned or selected by current user (personage_id).

Can you help me to write a proper query?

*How this works:*
With php I generate: List of spells | checkbox isSelected | checkBox isStudied

When I click on isSelected checkbox, a record in grimory will be added with current user and spell.

Comment: Did u get the answer?

Comment: What do you want to check in leaned column and selected column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

```
SELECT a.*, IFNULL(b.isLearned,0) as isLearned, 
IFNULL(b.isSelected,0) as isSelected
FROM Spell a 
LEFT JOIN Grimory b(ON b.spell_id =a.id 
   AND b.personage_id =:current_user_id)
WHERE a.category_id = :current_category_id
```

Comment: There are a problem: Grimory can be empty, and I need to display all records from Spells, so a user can choose some of them for "study".
I have updated my question with more infos.

Comment: @Diego : Are you sure you use my query as it is (don't you change `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JON` )? It must return all the rows from `Spell` regardless of rows in `Grimory`.

Comment: @a1ex07, `ON b.spell_id = a.id`, Spell does not have `spell_id` column.

Comment: @Diego: Yeah, I see. Sorry for typo, I'm used to name columns the same in each table. I also realized you need a filter by category_id. Fixing...

Comment: Ah-ha! Thanks, now it works. I have added a "group by" for mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Spell 
INNER JOIN Grimory
ON Spell.id = Grimory.spell_id 
WHERE (Grimory.isLearned = 1 OR Grimory.isSelected = 1)
AND Spell.category_id = 'YOUR CAT ID IS HERE'
```